# Separate the digits of an integer (C++)

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that takes an integer as input and outputs it with its digits spaced. The algorithm works fine but prints the digits in reverse order. To get the original order, I used a for loop. The problem is that it prints nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int countDigit(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n = n / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    int Num ;
    int sum = 0;
    int arr[100];

    cout <<"Enter an integer: " ;
    cin >> Num ;
    int c = countDigit(Num) ;
    for (int i = c; i > 0; i--)
    {   
        arr[i] = (Num % 10);
        Num = (Num / 10);
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    cout << " Your digits:";
 for (int x = 1 ; x <= c; x++)
    {
        cout << arr[x] << " " ;
        cout << sum ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My issue is here

```
for (int x = 1 ; x <= c; x++)
    {
        cout << arr[x] << " " ;
        cout << sum ;
    }
```

It prints nothing. What could be the problem ?

The input used is 1234
The expected output is 1 2 3 4

Comment: Please provide input used, and expected output.C++, are 0-based?

Comment: Please do some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. And think about what the value of `Num` will be after the previous loop.

Comment: DO you know what a debugger is?

Comment: And do you really want to call `countDigit` *every iteration* of the loop? Why not save the result into a variable, and use that variable instead? Preferably before the first loop (considering what it does).

Comment: not the problem: you can do counting of digits and extracting digits in a single loop. more related to the problem: you need to count the number of digits only once (not twice and certainly not in every iteration of a loop)

Comment: uhm please dont fix errors in your code. Fixed code should go to answers. Do you still get the same behaviour with this modified code?

Comment: why you are printing the sum in each iteration. Print the sum after the for loop

Comment: the code you posted does print something. Please at least try to keep your question consistent when you edit the code. I was about writing an answer but for your old code, you already had an answer, but for your old code...bottomline is: You had the chance for 2 answers, now you got 0 :/

Comment: I just saved the result of countDigit(Num) in variable c. I still get the same behaviour.

Comment: please add the input, desired and actual output in the question. I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. When I run this code it does print something

Comment: My take is that this would be a LOT easier if you just took the input as a string and verified that the entire string was a number (hint: that's a single STL function call and `if` check).

Comment: Arrays in C/C++ are 0 based so you are blowing up memory with your print.  Also, consider printing your digit array in reverse order.  Finally, `SingleDigitNumber + '0'` is a way to convert a single digit to a character if you wanted to go that route.

Comment: Your program prints `1 102 103 104 10`, as expected when you print the sum inside the lopp.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the function `countDigit` is wrong.

```
int countDigit(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n = n / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It returns 0 for the valid number 0 that has one digit.

The function can look the following way

```
size_t countDigit( int n, int base = 10 )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    do
    {
        ++count;
    } while ( n /= base );

    return count;
}
```

In this loop

```
for (int i = countDigit(Num); i > 0; i--)
{   
    arr[i] = (Num % 10);
    Num = (Num / 10);
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

the variable `Num` was changed. So in the next loop

```
for (int x = 1 ; x <= countDigit(Num) ; x++)
{
    cout << arr[x] << " " ;
    cout << sum ;
}
```

it will not have the original value You need to use an intermediate variable to make the calculation.

Also take into account that the use can enter a negative number.

**EDIT**: After you updated your code then you also need to move the output of the sum from the loop

```
for (int x = 1 ; x <= c; x++)
{
    cout << arr[x] << " " ;
}
cout << sum ;
```

And instead of the large integer array it is better to use an object of the type `std::string`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t countDigit( int n, int base = 10 )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    do
    {
        ++count;
    } while ( n /= base );

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    const int Base = 10;
    int num;

    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    size_t count = countDigit( num );
    std::string s( count, ' ' );

    int sum = 0;

    for ( ; count-- != 0; num /= Base )
    {
        int digit = num % Base; 
        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

        s[count] =  digit + '0'; 
        sum += digit;
    }

    std:: cout << "Your digits: ";
    for ( const auto &c : s ) std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';


    std::cout << "The sum of digits is " << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter an integer: -123456789
Your digits: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
The sum of digits is 45
```

Another approach is to write a recursive function that outputs digits and returns the sum of digits.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int recursive_sum( long long int n, long long int base = 10, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    long long int digit = n % base;

    if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

    unsigned int sum = digit + ( ( n /= base ) == 0 ? 0 : recursive_sum( n ) );

    os << digit << ' ';

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int num;

    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    unsigned int sum = recursive_sum( num );
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "The sum of digits is " << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output might look like

```
Enter an integer: -123456789
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
The sum of digits is 45
```

Comment: @downvoter: any suggestion how to improve the answer?

Comment: @StephanLechner at the time this answer was posted it was refering to cdoe that wasnt present in the question anymore. My guess is that the dv was due to that

Comment: Probably it is simpler to start `count` from 1 as it is not possible to have a number with 0 digits :)

Answer (score 0):

This gives the expected output. I assigned countDigit(Num) to c and wrote the sum to outside the loop.

```
int main()
{
    int Num ;
    int sum = 0;
    int arr[100];

    cout <<"Enter an integer: " ;
    cin >> Num ;
    int c = countDigit(Num); //edit 1

    // extracts the digits
    for (int i = c; i > 0; i--)
    {   
        arr[i] = (Num % 10);
        Num = (Num / 10);
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Your digits with spaces: ";
    // reverses the order
    for (int x = 1 ; x <= c ; x++)
    {
        cout << arr[x] << " " ;

    }
    cout << endl << "The sum of the digits is: " << sum ; // edit 2
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <std::integral T>
void printDigits(T const i) {
  for (auto const ch : std::to_string(i)) {
    std::printf("%c ", ch);
  }
  std::fflush(stdout);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QBgLNuMaD1aMSvfl)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a take that uses strings.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string input;
  std::size_t location;

  std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input);

  std::stoi(input, &location); // Don't care about the integer, just location

  if (location != input.length()) {
    std::cout << "Invalid Entry: Non-integer entered\n";
    return 1;
  }

  for (auto i : input) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  // Here's a one liner that requires <algorithm>
  // std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(), [](auto i) { std::cout << i << ' '; });
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I don't care about an integer at all. I can validate that only digits were entered and quit early if not. The only loop I need is for printing.

`stoi()` can return the integer, but I don't care about the integer. I just want to know how many characters were converted, and I learn that by feeding it the output argument location. Checking that location is the same as the string length ensures that only digits were entered. No decimal points, no extra letters, just numbers.

The caveats are that this might not fit into your requirements if this is an assignment. It also requires C++11, which is surprisingly not a given yet (for assignments, I get the industry arguments).